# jquery on change and multiple selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, multiple-instances

got a problem with having mutliple select dropdowns on a page, each of which has an associated change event. Each one works individually but if I have them both running, neither works. There are two functions, UpdateLanguages and UpdateNoChangeMotorSelection. I have two dynamically built dropdowns the user can select and when they choose from one of them, they update other areas of the page.

If I comment out either

```
$("#nochangemotorselection").html(nochangemotoroutput);
```

or

```
$('#language').html(languageoutput);
```

The remaining one works perfectly. But if I have both of them running, then although both select dropdowns populate, nothing happens when they are changed.

```
function UpdateLanguages()
    {
        $.getJSON('php/languages.json', function(data)
            {//get the languages json file
            $.each(data.languages, function(key, val)
                   { //for each line of data in the languages.json file, get the key/value pair
            if(val.language == currentlanguage)
                        {
                            $('#texttransmission').text(val.texttransmission); 
                            $('#textcontroller').text(val.textcontroller);
                            $('#textmotor').text(val.textmotor);
                            $('#currentlanguage').text(currentlanguage); //displays in variable table
                        }
                    }); 
            });
    }

function UpdateNoChangeMotorSelection()
    {
        $.getJSON('php/products.json', function(data)
            {
            $.each(data.products, function(key, val)
                   { 
            if(val.commercialname == nochangemotorid)
                        {
                            $('#nochangemotorspeed').text(val.speed); 
                            nochangemotorspeed = val.speed;
                            $('#nochangemotorefficiency').text(val.efficiencyclass);
                            nochangemotorefficiency = val.efficiencyclass;
                            $('#nochangemotorpower').text(val.power);
                            nochangemotorpower = val.power;
                            $('#nochangemotorpoles').text(val.poles);
                            nochangemotorpoles = val.pole;
                            $('#nochangemotorchosen').text(nochangemotorid);//displays in variable table
                        }
                    }); 
            });
    }
// select language JSON     
$.getJSON('php/languages.json', function(data){//get the languages json file
    var languageoutput = '<select id="language" name="language" class="language">'; //start a variable called output full of html
    $.each(data.languages, function(key, val){ //for each line of data in the languages.json file, get the key/value pair
    languageoutput += '<option>' +val.language+ '</option>';    //add to the variable 'output' with the value from the languages field
    });//end of each
    languageoutput += '</select>';//add to the variable 'output'
    $('#language').html(languageoutput);//output result to the div with the id="languages"
    $( "#language" ).on('change', function() {
          var selectedlanguage = "";
         $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
            selectedlanguage += $( this ).text();
            });
        currentlanguage = selectedlanguage;
        DoUpdate();
    });
}); 



// select product JSON 
$.getJSON('php/products.json', function(data){
    var nochangemotoroutput = '<select id="nochangemotorselection" name="nochangemotorselection" class="nochangemotorselection">'; 
    $.each(data.products, function(key, val){ 
    if (val.productrange != 'Transmission')
        {
        if (val.productrange != 'Controller')
            {
            nochangemotoroutput += '<option>' +val.commercialname+ '</option>'; 
            }   
        }
    });
    nochangemotoroutput += '</select> ';
    $("#nochangemotorselection").html(nochangemotoroutput);
    $( "#nochangemotorselection" ).on('change', function() {
          var selectednochangemotor = "";
         $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
            selectednochangemotor += $( this ).text();
            });
        nochangemotorid = selectednochangemotor;
        UpdateNoChangeMotorSelection(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: You're creating a dynamic select `<select id="language">` with `language` as id, at this point you just created select element and yet to append to DOM and then you're doing `$('#language').html(languageoutput)`, how does that work ? Do you already have a select element in your page with language id ?

Comment: No select element in the markup, have a div with the id="language" and it drops in there.

Comment: then your div and select element both have same id but id's are supposed to be unique right ? I suggest you change div ids to `language-div` and `nochangemotorselection-div`, that way it'll be easier to read and your code works :)

Comment: They are unique though as, like i say, if i comment out, for example, $("#nochangemotorselection").html(nochangemotoroutput); then the other one works fine.

Comment: I get that there is something conflicting but the id's and classes are all unique for each function so that can't be it?

Comment: Element IDs should be unique in your HTML not in your function :) Did you try with different names for divs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select` element id and the `div` container to which you're adding that select element have same IDs. I suggest you change your div container IDs to something meaningful like this in your HTML

```
<!-- container for languages -->
<div id="language-div"> </div> 

<!-- container for products -->
<div id="product-div"> </div>
```

Now make the corresponding changes to your script to use these new IDs.

```
    // select language JSON     
    $.getJSON('php/languages.json', function(data){
        var languageoutput = '<select id="language" name="language" class="language">'; 
        // add options to language
        languageoutput += '</select>';
        // now add it to your div
        $('#language-div').html(languageoutput);
       // register your change event on select element now
        $( "#language" ).on('change', function() {
              // your code
        }); 
   });

    // select product JSON 
    $.getJSON('php/products.json', function(data){
        var nochangemotoroutput = '<select id="nochangemotorselection" 
      name="nochangemotorselection" class="nochangemotorselection">'; 
        // add options to nochangemotorselection
        nochangemotoroutput += '</select> ';
        $("#product-div").html(nochangemotoroutput);
        $( "#nochangemotorselection" ).on('change', function() {
              // your code 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nope, this has no effect at all.

Comment: Are you positive that you changed IDs both in HTML and in script and no typos :) ?

Comment: yes, positive. I've gone back and double checked and definitely changed, both in the HTML and also in the script.

Comment: the dropdowns do populate and appear, the problem is they don't trigger the change event.

Comment: Ok one more thing `$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
            selectedlanguage += $( this ).text();
            });` . That code doesn't seem right. Basically you're trying to get select a dropdown with some value selected, you're not necessarily that it should select#language dropdown

Comment: Change that code to `var selectedlanguage = $(this).val();` in both the places

Comment: Nope, none at all. Just did a double check.

Comment: Hmm.. we'll try with delegated event handling. Change `$( "#nochangemotorselection" ).on('change',callback);`  to `$(document).on('#nochangemotorselection', 'change', callback);`

Comment: How exactly are you triggering change event event ? you're just changing the value in select drop down right ?

Comment: why callback instead of function()?

Comment: its your function() only, callback is just a general name :)

Comment: ah, ok. Unfortunately, still not working. I don't get it. Each one works exactly as expected on its own, its only when both drop downs are sent to the html that the problem occurs. And the problem isn't that they don't appear, they do. They just don't trigger the change!

Comment: Can you post your updated script in your question :-) ?

Comment: I've changed it all back to how it was as the changes made no difference at all. Like I say, it works when just one is on screen but not when both are so I know the actual dropdowns and changes works as I can see them.

Comment: This answer undoubtedly led to OP uncovering solution - +1

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else gets in the same situation, my error was that I was not defining 'which' of the selects the result was coming from. So instead of

```
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function().....
```

I needed

```
$( "select.languages option:selected" ).each(function()....
```

So that the on change knew which one it was refering to!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, Will. Well done on solving this problem.

Comment: Didn't i ask you to change that to `$(this).val()` in one of my comments ? ;-) Anyways it's cool you figured it out :-)

Comment: It's not a the $(this).val() point that it needed changing, it is at the select option:selected point. If thats what you were trying to get across, sorry, I must have misunderstood you.